# .pes file creator

Tags: file, creation, file-conversion

I am looking into starting my own brand of clothing. I have the sample material and a logo but the embroider has asked me to provide a PES file for her to use with her Brother Embroidery Machine. I have looked into changing my .jpg or my .png file into a .pes file but i have had no luck. It looks like there is a lot more to it than a simple conversion.

My question here is would anyone be able to create a .pes file for me if i provide the logo? If not would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on how i could create it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few programs that can do this conversion, but it usually requires a bit of know how, and usually the software is fairly expensive. Here are a couple of the more affordable products.

http://www.sandscomputing.com/id20.html
http://www.buzztools.com/buzz-2-Stitches.asp

You might want to turn the image to a more embroidery style image first, which you can do with the following:

http://www.drawstitch.com/index.php/Products/Embroidery_Effect/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Embroidermodder](http://embroidermodder.sourceforge.net/)? It's a famous open source solution for editing digital embroidery files.

It's strange that its creator Josh Varga answered this question without pointing you to it!